# search websphere portal 6 and websphere portal 8

Tags: websphere-portal

I have configured remote search and configured the collections. When in default theme, if I search I can see the search results in the search center. However when in custom theme  when I search I see search-results.html page not found error. Could some one point me to resources to debug this issue for version 6 and version 8 of websphere portal. Also I want to show search results of external application like Alfresco using portal 8.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the search results can be seen in the default theme, but not in the custom theme using the same portlet, it seems that the issue is with the custom theme itself.

Make sure that all the necessary DOJO modules and configuration is included in your theme by comparing the HTML page and resource loading (e.g. using fiddler or firebug), and compare with the original theme. Check for any javascript errors or 404s during the page load.

Here are some theme-related troubleshooting guides:

[Collecting Data: Problems with modular-based themes in WebSphere Portal](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21616359)

[Troubleshooting Web 2.0 issues in Portal 6.1](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS3NNG_6.1.0/com.ibm.wp.zos.doc/dev/w2thm_trbl.html?lang=en)

[Deploying Custom Portal 8 Themes - Step By Step Guide](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/dx/Deploying_and_developing_IBM_WebSphere_Portal_8_themes_A_step-by-step_guide)

Also, you can index and search a remote site such as an Alfresco-based site using WebSphere Portal Search, but it is limited to public pages only (i.e. portal search will not be able to apply any security to those results that are access-controlled) - .e.g:

[Crawling a remote portal site](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHRKX_8.0.0/admin/srcsrchngpubportpgs.html)